# Getting object spread to work with webpack.config and babelrc files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying to get the object spread operator to work with my react project. It comes up with a syntax error:

[image: spread operator error]

I have tried using `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` as described by the babel [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

After a bit of research I also tried the config described in GitHub issues for [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170):
[image: babelrc config for spread operator]

Please see my **.babelrc** file below:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "retainLines": true
}
```

And my **webpack.config** file below:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test:/\.scss$/,
        use: [{
                loader: 'style-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }]
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true,
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
   publicPath: '/js/',
   port: 3000
 }
};
```

And my code where I'm using the spread operator is:

```
import * as types from '../types/types'; 

const initialState ={
    mesage:''
}

export default function doodlesReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_MESSAGE' :
        return {…state, message: action.payload.message}
        default :
        return state
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me try and figure out the right configuration to use the object spread operator?

Comment: how does your code look like?

Comment: `...` is not an operator, and object spread/rest is not part of ES2015, which is why you need an additional plugin to convert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're listing your presets in both `.babelrc` and `webpack.config`, try moving it all out to only one of them, i.e. only `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

**Edit:** Also instead of using `es2015` preset which has now been deprecated install an `env` preset `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env` and in `.babelrc` replace `es2015` with `env`.

**Edit 2:** The `…` that you're using uses some non-supported character encoding, you must have copy pasted it from somewhere which messed up the encoding, replace it with `...`.

Comment: still got the same error I'm afraid, thanks for the idea though, I'm pretty new with babel, webpack and react.

Comment: instead of using ES2015 install `babel-preset-env` and in babelrc add it as "env"

Comment: Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|     <Provider store={store}>
|         <App />
|     </Provider>

Comment: @R.Thompson The edit 2 is where your initial problem comes from, change it back to whatever was working for you and make the change suggested in edit 2 and then try to add the new env preset after you get that working